# How can I store a class name when a user clicks on a button so it can be used as a default on next visit?

Tags: javascript

I am using the following to change the class associated with the  tag:

```
<html lang="en" class="darkBlue">

    <button name="darkBlue"
       onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className=this.name">Blue</button>
    <button name="black"
       onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className=this.name">Blue</button>
```

How can I use localstorage to store what has been clicked and make it so that when the user visits the page then this is the default. So there's no flicker then should I have some javascript inside of the `<header>` tag of the page?

Comment: Is that not the old way of doing it? I thought people are now using localstorage ?

Comment: Both methods can be used, and localstorage did not "replace" cookie , but the former cannot be read by the server directly. (Is it useful in your case ?)

Comment: I just need something local and not read by the server. As there will be only two or three buttons then I was thinking some call to localstorage could be coded inside the onclick just to keep it in one place. Then somehow I need to have something to check if there's a localstorage entry as the page loads so I can set the theme color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

**HTML**

```
<button name="darkBlue" onclick="getButtonColor(this.name)" >Blue</button>
<button name="black" onclick="getButtonColor(this.name)" >Black</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
 if(localStorage.buttonColor) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className = localStorage.buttonColor
}

function getButtonColor(buttonName) {
    localStorage.buttonColor= buttonName;
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className = buttonName
}
```

Comment: This looks very good. I will try this out now and update your answer soon. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

well here is simple way to do

### HTML

```
<button name="darkBlue" onclick="handleClick(this.name);">Blue</button>
<button name="black" onclick="handleClick(this.name);">Blue</button>
```

### JavaScript

```
if (localStorage.btnClass) {
    //alert(localStorage.getItem('btnClass'));

    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className = localStorage
            .getItem('btnClass');

}
function handleClick(btnName) {
    localStorage.setItem('btnClass', btnName);
};
```

thanks anne for pointing IDs should be unique

Comment: But how can I get the value from localstorage and use this to set the class on html with: document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className=this.name;  You are using #btn as an ID but I think IDs should be unique.